# Hiding and showing a div at item post

Tags: javascript, php, osclass

I am a student and I have problems on item post. I am looking for a hide show script based on `parentCatId` and `catId`!

This is the div I try to hide and or show! `div class="item-post-lot-area"`

```
<div class="item-post-lot-area">
  <label for="s_lotsize">
    <?php _e('Lot Area', 'ctg_housing'); ?>
  </label>
  <div class="row collapse prefix-radius">
    <div class="item-post-area-sign columns">
      <span class="prefix"><?php echo osc_get_preference('metric','ctg_housing_theme'); ?></span>
    </div>
    <div class="item-post-area-number columns">
      <input type="number" name="s_lotsize" id="s_lotsize" value="<?php if(isset($housingOut['s_lotsize'])) { echo $housingOut['s_lotsize'];} ?>" >
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

what i try!

`item-post-lot-area` field will all time show when loading the page!
And will hide when selected the following `parentCatId` and `catId`

```
<option value="28">Vacation</option>
  <select id="catId" name="catId" class="valid">
    <option value="28">Select Subcategory</option>
    <option value="29">Pension House</option>
    <option value="30">Inn / Motel</option>
    <option value="31">Hotel &amp; Resort</option>
</option>
  </select>
  <select id="catId" name="catId" class="valid">
    <option value="32">Select Subcategory</option>
    <option value="33">Space</option>
    <option value="34">Office</option>
    <option value="35">BPO</option>
    <option value="36">Economic</option>
  </select>
```

Can someone explain me how to do this?

Thanks

Comment: where's your js script?

Comment: There is a load of examples on js/jQuery scripts to show/hide divs..just ask Mr Google. He knows loads of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You can show or hide using Jquery,

```
<script>
$( "select" )
  .change(function() {
    $( "select option:selected" ).each(function() {
     $("#item-post-lot-area").hide();
    });

  })
</script>
```

check the link to know more https://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: yes but then it will hide all time i need this only to hide when the upper categories are selected!

Comment: This code will work when the select option is selected only. It works in such a way that on select element is changed ie. [when a option is selected] then the div will hide. 
First time it will be visible only once a option is selected , then the div will get hidden. Check and let me know,

Comment: wrong reason i have 60 other categories extra and it will hid on everything!